# How to fetch and inspect mongodb index options using the go mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go-driver

I need to get all indexes of a specific collection and inspect their index options using the go mongo driver (go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo)

Here is the code I am using:

```
cur, err := collection.Indexes().List(ctx)
if err != nil {
   return err
}

for cur.Next(ctx) {
    index := &mongo.IndexModel{}
    if err := cur.Decode(index); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not decode index: %w", err)
    }

   // access index.Options
   // ...
}
```

However, the `index` variable is empty, so I guess it could not be decoded into the `IndexModel` type. I don't get an error either. Can somebody give advice on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Did you see the [example](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#example-IndexView.List) in the docs? Not the best example, but better than nothing.

Comment: @rustyx, that example basically produces a slice of `bson.M` objects, and does not attempt to decode them. The call `cur.Decode()` in the OP's example basically is an attempt to decode a single such `bson.M` object as a `mongo.IndexModel`. My take is that what `collection.Indexes().List()` iterates over are not `mongo.IndexModel` but I have no idea what they are. I'd first try to inspect those `bson.M` objects without trying to decode them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a collection with indexes as listed in `mongo` shell:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.books"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "author" : 1,
                        "title" : 1
                },
                "name" : "author_1_title_1",
                "ns" : "test.books"
        }
]
```

The same indexes listed using *golang*:

```
collection := client.Database("test").Collection("books")
indexView := collection.Indexes()
opts := options.ListIndexes().SetMaxTime(2 * time.Second)
cursor, err := indexView.List(context.TODO(), opts)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var result []bson.M
if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &result); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, v := range result {
    for k1, v1 := range v {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", k1, v1)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

The output is:

```
v: 2
key: map[_id:1]
name: _id_
ns: test.books

v: 2
unique: true
key: map[author:1 title:1]
name: author_1_title_1
ns: test.books
```

---

[ EDIT ADD ] This is slightly different version `result` loop with *map* printed as key-values:

```
for _, v := range result {
    for k1, v1 := range v {
        if reflect.ValueOf(v1).Kind() == reflect.Map {
            v1a := v1.(primitive.M)
            fmt.Printf("%v: {\n", k1)
            for k2, v2 := range v1a {
                fmt.Printf("  %v: %v\n", k2, v2)
            }
            fmt.Printf("}\n")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", k1, v1)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

The output:

```
key: {
  _id: 1
}
name: _id_
ns: test.books
v: 2

v: 2
unique: true
key: {
  title: 1
  author: 1
}
name: author_1_title_1
ns: test.books
```

Comment: thanks, so seems like decoding the output into a `mongo.IndexModel` is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The driver also exposes `ListSpecifications` method. It returns the `IndexSpecification` with index information.

```
collection.Indexes().ListSpecifications(ctx)
```